# Is it wrong to use a separate method for a scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

An exercise in the introduction to java programming book I am currently working through requires me to retrieve input from the command line using the scanner class.  Each example in the book (and the code I have seen here) creates and uses a scanner object in the same method it is needed in, such as:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DemoScanner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your first name: ");
        String firstName = inputDevice.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter your middle name: ");
        String middleName = inputDevice.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter your last name: ");
        String lastName = inputDevice.nextLine();

        inputDevice.close();

        System.out.println("Your name is " + firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName);
    }
}
```

I was wondering why this method is preferred over something like the following (especially since the execise requires me to retrieve input for nine strings)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DemoScanner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String firstName = prompt("Enter your first name: ");
        String middleName = prompt("Enter your middle name: ");
        String lastName = prompt("Enter your last name: ");

        System.out.println("Your name is " + firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName);
    }

    private static String prompt(String message) {
        Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(message);
        return inputDevice.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind I am new to both Java and programming in general.

Comment: There's nothing wrong using a seperate method, but you should close scanner after use, its not there

Comment: This question seems quite opinion-based, as responses can range from either agreeing/disagreeing based on personal preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with doing it that way, and it very well may save you a few lines in the long run, but it's not common because you can create a Scanner once and reuse it, as you've done above.

It's all style-based, but using one Scanner multiple times is fairly straightforward and avoids unnecessary complexity in your code, which is important (especially in larger-scale projects).

When you're going through the code line-by-line, your first example is much more readable to me, but that's just my opinion, as this is a fairly subjective question. The only real downside is that you're creating a new Scanner every time you call the `prompt()` method, which is unnecessary.

Also note that you forgot to close the Scanner in the method.

Answer (score -1):

In your case you are creating the Scanner object for every call of the prompt method which is not great practice.

Also you are not closing the Scanner.

IMHO the book's code is reads easier...